# Get html content from auth protected route inside laravel app?

Tags: php, laravel, curl, laravel-5, guzzle

I want to get with (curl) guzzle html content of a other page inside my laravel app.

The classic way would be:

```
$client = new Client();
$client = $client->request('GET', route('print.page'))->getBody();
```

The problem is, all this routes are auth protected and I get there only html from my login page.

I tried to send login trough guzzle again but I think this is not a good idea with double login.

Is there any better way to get html from this protected route?

Comment: If the route is protected then you’d need to supply the auth credentials/flow that is needed. If you normally grab a token then get that and add it to the curl headers.

Comment: Please add more context. From where is this called (Console or Web)? Do you have authenticated user at the time of call? Do you have access to the current request()?

Comment: 1. It will be called only from web. 2. Yes, at this time the user is authenticated 3. I have the current request, but I need the content from a other page, inside the same app of course. @commonsense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you calling this inside a controller **and** you have a current authenticated user, you have to get the session name and the real session id:

```
public function FooController() 
{
    $name = Session::getName();
    $sessionId = $_COOKIE[$name];

    $cookieJar = CookieJar::fromArray([
        $name => $sessionId,
    ], 'example.com');

    $client = new Client();
    $body = $client->request( // changed the variable from $client to $body here
        'GET', 
        route('print.page'), 
        ['cookies' => $cookieJar]
    )->getBody(); 
}
```